# Beautifulsoup grabs only first item of the table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have again a problem with scraping. When scraping table items, it only adds first item of the both tables, instead of expected table values. Can you please let me know what is my mistake?

Thank you in advance!

```
    for pagenumber in range (0,2):
    url = 'https://www.autowereld.nl/volkswagen/?mdl=volkswagen_golf|volkswagen_golf-alltrack|volkswagen_golf-cabriolet|volkswagen_golf-plus|volkswagen_golf-sportsvan|volkswagen_golf-variant&p='
    txt = requests.get(url + str(pagenumber))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(txt.text, 'lxml')
    soup_table = soup.findAll('article', class_="item")

    for article in soup_table:
        for car in article.findAll('a'):
            link = car.get('href')
            sub_url = 'https://www.autowereld.nl' + link

            sub_soup = requests.get(sub_url)
            sub_soup_txt = BeautifulSoup(sub_soup.text, 'lxml')

            titles = []
            places = []
            specifications = []

            for item in sub_soup_txt.findAll('div', {'class':'listhead'}):
                title = item.find('h1', {'class': 'title'}).text.strip()
                titles.append(title)

            for item in sub_soup_txt.findAll('div', {'class':'user'}):
                place = item.find('span', {'class': 'zipcode'}).text.strip()
                places.append(place)

            for item in sub_soup_txt.findAll('table',{'class':'specifications'}):
                term = item.find('td', {'class': 'term'}).text.strip()
                value = item.find('td', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip()
                specifications.append([term,value])
```

```
Volkswagen Golf - 1.0 TSI 85pk Trendline + Navigatie + Cruise Control
8263AM Kampen
[['Prijs', '€ 14.450'], ['Aantal deuren', '5-deurs']]
```

Comment: I would recommend refactoring your code. It looks like you've built an array with titles, places, specifications within 3 nested for loop. This doesn't get returned, so you should expect 1 car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should findAll `<tr>s`

```
for item in sub_soup_txt.findAll('table',{'class':'specifications'}):
    for tr in item.findAll('tr'):
        term = tr.find('td', {'class': 'term'}).text.strip()
        value = tr.find('td', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip()
        specifications.append([term,value])
```